# How to get content between option tags of select in java

Tags: java, jsp

I have a drop down in jsp page i need content of option tags which i will use as a file name for saving while exporting.

```
<select id="country"  name="regionCode">
                        <option value=".com" selected="selected">USA</option>
                        <option value=".co.uk">UK</option>
                        <option value=".co.in">India</option>
                        <option value=".com.au">Australia</option>
```

anyhow value is obtained in the servlet to process, but i need USA, UK, India, Australia

Comment: you can get these data using innerHTML or innerText in javascript pass it in url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that's not possible as when you will submit the form only the value is passed down of the selected item and not the label. Label is just used for rendering purpose. if you need something like US/UK, you should save it in value field.

Or if you need value to be as is, then you could may be create a map with key as what value you have and label that you are showing on the screen like:

```
 Map<String, String> valueLabelMap = new ...
 map.put(".com", "USA");
```

And then when you get selected option, you do a lookup on the map to get the value.

Comment: any other way to get that content between option tags

Comment: Unfortunately no friend. I have mentioned the work around as well in my answer. Or you could create a hack with hidden field that you populate with selected option may be via JS and send over to servlet.

Comment: thank you @SMA i think its better to read from properties file based on the value like .com=USA .co.uk=UK etc

Comment: yeah i agree that's the best option you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but it is not a optimal solution...There is no other way also to get the data..

```
<option value=".co.uk:UK">UK</option>
```

In the server side use.

```
String s=request.getParameter("regionCode");
String s1=s.split(":")[1];
System.out.println(s1);
```

Comment: thank you sirish for your reply, i'm going to look up properties file based on the input like .com=USA .co.uk=UK etc